# How to draw this implicit function?

Tags: plotting

I want to draw an image of this implicit function $x^2 - y^2 = \tan ( y^x)$, but I get a lot of warning messages when I draw the image using the following method:

```
ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2 == Tan[y^x], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50]
```

What can I do to create a complete and clear image of it?

[image]

*(The drawing software used in the above figure is [`Grafeq`](http://www.peda.com/grafeq/).)*

And the following method of [`chyanog`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2090/chyanog) can draw the outline of this image, but how to further improve its drawing speed?

```
With[{pow = Sign[#] Abs[#]^#2 &}, 
 ContourPlot[
  Cos[pow[y, x]] (x^2 - y^2) == Sin[pow[y, x]], {x, -2 Pi, 
   2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, MaxRecursion -> 1, PlotPoints -> 50]]
```

[image]

Comment: Everything would be much simpler if `y>0`. Negative `y` does not make much sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation `x^2 - y^2 == Tan[y^x]` is equivalent to the series of the equations `ArcTan[x^2 - y^2] == y^x + k*Pi`, where `k∈ Integers`. Therefore,

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[Table[ArcTan[x^2 - y^2] == y^x + k*Pi, {k, -2, 2}]], {x, -10,   10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

does the job
[image]